# what will happen if i implement multi threading on a system that already uses 100% of my CPU

Tags: multithreading

i had an exam today about multi threads, and one of the questions was:

"what do you think will happen, if we will convert a system that uses 100% of the CPU to multi thread"

actually i wasn't sure what is the right answer, because i know that the main reason of using threads is to improve the usage of the CPU, and to improve running time of course.

so when we already using 100% of the CPU, and still convert our program to support multi threading, what can happen?

- nothing?
- something like a crash? ( like when i'm trying to play a game that is way to much for my PC )

i'll be happy to get any clearing about this topic :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a big question first: What does "100%" mean? In one OS, 100% of a quad core CPU means "all four cores running at 100%", and on another it means "one core is running at 100%, you can use three more cores and use 400%".

If all cores are used at 100%, then the CPU is doing as much work as it can do. Adding threads cannot make it do more work; the amount of work will be unchanged. The threads that you had before will make slower progress, but the new threads will also make some progress. You are not going to finish quicker.

If one core of a quad core CPU is used at 100%, then adding a thread means another core can also do 100% work, so you are doing twice as much work in the same time. Adding two more threads means you can do four times as much work. Adding more threads won't help.